# How to provide Detail description of the Logo?

Tags: logo, copyright, trademark

One of my client requires detail description of the Logo to provide it to copyright lawer so they can register the logo.

What kind of detail is normally provided here ? Any example would be great.

Thanks
Zerus

Comment: This is a legal question to ask the lawyer.

Comment: Describe the logo as if you were explaining to a blind person what it looks like and why it's unique.

Comment: Modern-day blazoning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blazon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Describe the logo and what makes it unique in a short paragraph.
It is usually possible to include the logo in the same document.

Answer (score 1):

For one a detailed style guide breaking down the padding of the logo color and different uses of color or ordinations of the lockup. The more you give them the better because it will help them make a strong case about the logo and make it easier to get it trademarked. Also just ask a the lawyer what he wants he might want something special.